# Xamarin developed app using CloudKit is still cross-platform?

Tags: ios, xamarin, cloudkit, multiplatform

Read [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/intro_to_cloudkit/) an article how CloudKit can be accessed / used from Xamarin. Does it mean Android version still able to access / store data in CloudKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `CloudKit` is specifically for iOS. The methods of authentication are based on device and Apple ID, and the framework is proprietary by Apple.

Comment: One of the first lines on that page is: 'iCloud APIs enable iOS 8 applications to store data in iCloud' so I guess the answer is indeed no. Xamarin is a multi platform development tool. It looks like it's possible to use a platform specific API